# Animated Presentation Navigation

Tags: presentation, design

Some days ago, I saw an animated presentation, that was very awesome. I am trying to google but not able to find the way to how to create it in Microsoft Office or Libre Office.

There have a lot of image sliders presentation like that are available on internet, but I want presentation with slides. I have attached an example of slider [HERE](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/cover-flow-remade-with-css-and-jquery/cover-flow/).

**Requirement**: 1. First slides have links as thumbnails to another slides, 2. when I clicked on any slide, it open that slides. 3. when I click next button or click on slide then next slide will displayed and previous slide will fade out 4. at end of the slide first slide will open again.

Comment: Gimmicks!! What was the content like? Maybe try [Prezi](http://prezi.com).

Comment: Might be [Vue](http://vue.tufts.edu/).

Comment: @DaveClarke Gimmicks are good - for a certain type of audience! I think Prezi is not the right tool for what the OP is asking. I remember listening to one presentation made with Prezi. It looked like one big canvas and I got dizzy from the animations.

Comment: Far more often than not, animations distract from the presentation. I'm much more likely to remember a well put together `beamer` presentation than a shoddy Prezi job replete with distracting and annoyingly slow transitions.

Comment: http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/ is also a nifty-looking one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wide variety of presentation tools with all kinds of features. However, for an *academic presentation* (I assume that this is what the question implies, otherwise it is off-topic on this site), animated transitions *between slides* and, for the most part, *on a slide* are **highly recommended against**. The main reason is that they significantly **distract** an audience from the *essence* of the presentation, thus, negatively impacting both the audience and the presenter.

When referring to the **on-slide transitions** above, I said "for the most part", because there are cases, when on-slide animated transitions are actually appropriate and helpful. For example, when a particular slide describes dynamic elements or nature of a system, it is helpful to illustrate the dynamics of changing state of the system's elements or features with *animated or otherwise dynamic transitions*.

Speaking about **presentation tools**, most software offerings (standalone and online services) offer the rather basic features that you mention in your requirements. For example, besides Microsoft Office and Libre Office, you can take a look at academically-focused `Beamer` (very flexible and highly recommended) and `knitr` software, as well as online services [Bunkr](http://bunkrapp.com), [Speaker Deck](http://speakerdeck.com), already mentioned [RevealJS](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js), [Prezi](http://prezi.com) (don't like it and don't recommend - similarly to @Nox, I get dizzy from their standard transitions), [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/mac/keynote) (AFAIK, it's Mac-only), [SlideRocket](http://www.sliderocket.com) and many more. If your subject matter allows *story telling* (which is what should be the core of ANY presentation, regardless of the domain), but in a *more visual way*, check [Amazon StoryTeller](http://studios.amazon.com/storyteller) and [PowToon](http://www.powtoon.com).

Comment: To complete that answer, please note that [Beamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29) (the best tool, IMHO) is actually a Latex package, so a bit of Latex-knowledge is required to get started.

Comment: @kebs: Thank you for the comment. I'm [well aware](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aleksandr_Blekh/publication/275644724_Presentation_slides_for_dissertation_defense/links/5541d3a60cf2718618dcba8f.pdf?ev=pub_int_doc_dl&origin=publication_detail&inViewer=true) of Beamer's relation to LaTeX :-), but agree with you on both other points on Beamer (being the best - at least, for producing academic presentations - and requiring some LaTeX knowledge - the needed level IMHO is proportional to desired aesthetics and complexity of a presentation).